# Model for different kinds of print jobs

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am trying to calculate the print cost base on different paper size, single side or double side. So here is the detail:

A4, job type single sided:
*15 cents - black and white page
*25 cents - color page.

A4, job type double sided:
*10 cents - black and white page
*20 cents - color page.

Also need to support for other paper sizes will be added in the future.

And according to my design, developer can just create a A5 class for example to support other paper size, and add other condition in the factory class.

Could someone review my code and help me on whether I have to use interface instead of abstract class?

Here is my code:

PageBase:

```
public abstract class PageBase {
    abstract double GetCost(int total, int color, boolean isSingleSide);
    abstract void CalculateUnitPrice(boolean isSingleSide);
}
```

A4Page Class:

```
public class A4Page extends PageBase {
    public double blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost;
    public double colorPrintUniCost;

    @Override
    public double GetCost(int total, int color, boolean isSingleSide) {
        CalculateUnitPrice(isSingleSide);
        return color* colorPrintUniCost + (total-color)* blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost;
    }

    @Override
    public void CalculateUnitPrice(boolean isSingleSide) {
        if (isSingleSide) {
            this.blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost = 0.15;
            this.colorPrintUniCost = 0.25;
        }
        else {
            this.blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost = 0.10;
            this.colorPrintUniCost = 0.20;
        }
    }
}
```

PageFactory:

```
public class PageFactory {

    public PageBase GetPage(String pageType) {
        switch (pageType.toUpperCase()) {
            case "A4":
                return new A4Page();
            default:
                return new A4Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main() {
        //read
        PageFactory pageFactory = new PageFactory();
        PageBase page = pageFactory.GetPage("A4");
        page.GetCost(0,0,false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Design

you should consider to define the properties of the page in factory, that's where it should be located.

```
public PageBase GetPage(String pageType) {
    switch (pageType.toUpperCase()) {
        case "A4": return new Page(0.15, 0.25, 0.10, 0.20);
}
```

### Programming

### 1. Page

you should not try to subclass the page since it is not required, the only difference between each page are the prices (so far). Therefore you don't need subclasses - it is just a page (not a base Page or anything else)

And even more you should could instanciate the class with all properties during construction (as shown above, dependency injection)

```
public class Page {

    private final double blackWhiteSinglePageUnitCost;
    private final double colorSinglePageUnitCost;
    private final double blackWhiteDoublePageUnitCost;
    private final double colorDoublePageUnitCost;

    public Page(double bwSingle, double colorSingle, double bwDouble, double colorDouble){
        blackWhiteSinglePageUnitCost= bwSingle;
        colorSinglePageUnitCost= bwDouble;
        blackWhiteDoublePageUnitCost= bwSingle;
        colorDoublePageUnitCost= colorDouble;
    }
```

what can be kept ist `GetCost` but should be renamed int `getCost()` but you can totally skip `CalculateUnitPrice`, see below

### 2. PageType

if you use a certain format you should use Enums to define the Format of the sheet. that would free you from abusing Strings as datatypes

```
enum PageType {A4, A5, LETTER };
```

### 3. bringing things together

when we use all these hints from above we have to adjust some more code, to make the programm run again

`Page.class` must be modified we can calculate the price on-the-fly because we already know anything required to calculate the price:

```
public double getCost(int total, int color, boolean isSingleSided){
    int bw = total - color;
    if(isSingleSided){
        return bw * blackWhiteSinglePageUnitCost + color * colorSinglePageUnitCost ;
    else{
        return bw * blackWhiteDoublePageUnitCost + color * colorDoublePageUnitCost ;
    }

}
```

`PageFactory`must be modified - first the method signature must be java conform, namely `getPage` not `GetPage`. then you switch over the enum type instead of an String. That lets you handle invalid inputs.

```
public Page getPage(PageType pageType) { 
    switch (pageType) {
        case PageType.A4:
            return ...;   
        case PageType.A5:
            return ...;   
        case PageType.LETTER:
            return ...;            
    }
}
```

if you use this in action (in your `main` method ) it would be finally that appearance:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main() {
        PageFactory pageFactory = new PageFactory();
        Page page = pageFactory.getPage(PageType.A4);
        double cost = page.getCost(0,0,false);
    }
}
```